# What do you call the menu that pop up after clicking the infopath rich text field & how to change the position?

Tags: infopath, rich-text

In a web based infopath form for SharePoint (2007), whenever you click on a rich text field box, a menu will pop up showing a few icons that can help you to format the formatting of the text in your rich text field box. (Such as Bold or Underline)

So, what is the menu called?

Also, is it possible not to have it position at the top? (Can it be position on the right or left of the rich text field box?)

Here the menu that I am trying to say as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its a "rich text editor" that inherits from SharePoint RTE control. It opens up with in a "Modal Dialog Box" and you can position it writing some amount of client object model code inside the masterpage of the site where the infopath forms are.

You need to work your way around javascript and css to achieve this.

Learn to position a modal window :

http://akifkamalsyed.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/fix-the-position-of-sharepoint-2010-modaldialog/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx

http://melick-rajee.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-make-custom-page-modal-dialog-in.html

http://yellowheart.tistory.com/archive/20101111